# Using scanf to read an integer with nothing else but a newline character

Tags: c, scanf

Is there a way to use scanf (without using any other I/O function) to check whether the user input exists only of a single integer with nothing following it?

For example:

```
int g;
while(scanf("%d", &g)!=1){
    printf("\nincorrect input, try again");
}
```

This works fine for input like "/" or "-" but when you input "54.32" then it will read until the ".", the read count of scanf will be 1 and 54 will be stored in g. Is there a way to check if the input consists solely of a single integer followed by nothing but a newline character?

I would like to know if there exists a solution without using fgets or any other IO function?

Comment: scanf is for reading formatted input.  It is not useful for unformatted entry.

Comment: `"%d%c"` and then if the return is 2 and the character isn't `'\n'` -- extraneous characters exist. (but you really should do all user-input with `fgets()` and if needed conversions with `sscanf()`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> to check solely of a single integer followed by nothing but a newline character

Use `"%n"`  to record number of characters scanned, if it gets that far.

```
int n = 0;
scanf("%d*1[\n]%n", &g, &n);
if (n > 0) puts("input consists solely of a single integer followed by a newline");
```

---

If the result is *not* as hoped, additional code needed to cope with the errant input.

I recommend using `fgets()` to solve the larger problem.

Comment: I see the test was reversed, It just took a bit to psych out that a matching-failure was used to prevent `"%n"` from being reached. I still need `"%d%*1[\n]%n"` to get the desired behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Edit because I misunderstood the question: what about this?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int n;
    char c;

    scanf("%d", &n);

    scanf(" %c", &c) ? printf("incorrect input, try again\n") : printf("%d\n", n);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OP did ask for "followed by nothing but a newline character".  This answer does not detect  if a newline successfully followed an `int`.   It does match the ttitle.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica the OP asked to read `54` when the user ener `54.32` and that's a float, or an int followed by a dot, followed by another int. In any case the program works even for intgeers followed by just a newline.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Re-reading the question, I may actually got it wrong. I am sorry.

Comment: OP  posted goals are a bit contradictory and do not address what should remain unread when input is not as expected.  IAC,  OP liked this answer

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica well, even if he liked the answer I edited it to match what he's asking in the question. Thanks for letting me notice my blunder

Comment: [`fflush(stdin);` is undefined behavior](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.5.2p2), although some implementations support it.

Comment: So better to use an `fgets`?

Comment: Excuse me for the confusion, I have adjusted the title to fit the question body better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the assignment-suppressing format operator to extract everything (anything) after the integer, and the *number-of-characters-read* format specifier to see whether that matched anything, without having to store it anywhere.

See your [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf).

Eg,

```
int g, gchars, xchars;
scanf("%d%n%*s%n", &g, &gchars, &xchars);
if (xchars > gchars)
    printf("%d extra characters discarded after integer %d\n", xchars-gchars, g);
```

Comment: `%*s`  consumes any newline after the `int` that _may be_ present.  It cannot be use to distinguish if a newline followed the `int` or something else.